# List of organization names

Tags: data-request, usa, business

I am looking for a dataset containing:

- organization names

Optionally:

- abbreviation of the organization name
- location of the organization (e.g., in which state)
- size of the organization (e.g., number of employees, or revenues)

I mostly interested in the United States.

.

Comment: Please describe 'organization'. Where does this differ from e.g. company?

Answer (score 3):

not sure what you mean exactly by organization, but i believe you seek data that can be found in open corporates. you can drill down to data available in the US from their site:
https://opencorporates.com/